# Household material to mimic touches?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, touchscreen

I'm using my Android 5.0 tablet as a drawing board, but it is hard to draw small details with finger. So, is there any common household material to mimic touch.

I already tried pencil, but it won't works.

[I **do not** want to buy a touch-stick or something]

Comment: Not even most touch-sticks would achieve good precision, believe me...

Comment: @Andy finally, I found a way: Wrapping aluminium foil around any edgy object such as pencil works. But, you are right it doesn't have good precision. (Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5mJVnuQTXo)